# add class to input and label when datepicker is active?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, input, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

I'm trying to create a form with styled input (sort of inspired by shopify's check out page) where the labels will show up when the user starts typing in the input. Everything seems working perfectly until I tried to add jQuery UI's datepicker widget.

Here's what my form looks like before typing in:

[image]

And this is what it looks like when I type in something:

[image]

As you can see, the label "birthday" is supposed to display after the user selected their birthday from the datepicker widget. But nothing shows up unless the user keys in the date themselves... any suggestion what I could do with the code?

Here's my jQuery:

```
// input
$('input[type="text"], input[type="password"]').on('keyup blur', function(){
    tmpval = $(this).val();
    if(tmpval == '') {
        $(this).removeClass('active')
        .siblings('label').removeClass('active');
    } else {
        $(this).addClass('active')
        .siblings('label').addClass('active');
    }
});
// date picker
$('.datepicker').datepicker({
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    yearRange: "-100:+0"
});
```

And here's part of my html:

```
<li>
    <label class="label" for="first_name">First name</label>
    <input type="text" id="first_name" placeholder="First name" />
</li>
<li>
    <label class="label" for="last_name">Last name</label>
    <input type="text" id="last_name" placeholder="Last name" />
</li>
<li>
    <label class="label" for="birthday">Birthday</label>
    <input type="text" id="birthday" class="datepicker" placeholder="Birthday" />
</li>
```

Any help would be appreciated! thanks!

(Also apologies if any of my words doesn't make sense since English isn't my first language.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you need run the code which expose the label when user select a date (because neither of the events `keyup` and `blur` are not fired).
You can do this by using the [`onSelect`](https://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-onSelect) callback.

Something like:

```js
// input
$('input[type="text"], input[type="password"]').on('keyup blur', function() {
  handleLabel($(this));
});
// date picker
$('.datepicker').datepicker({
  changeMonth: true,
  changeYear: true,
  yearRange: "-100:+0",
  onSelect: function() {
    // Keep in mind that maybe the $(this) now reference to something else so you need to serach for the relvent Node
    handleLabel($(this));
  }
});

function handleLabel(elm) {
  tmpval = elm.val();
  if (tmpval == '') {
    elm.removeClass('active')
      .siblings('label').removeClass('active');
  } else {
    elm.addClass('active')
      .siblings('label').addClass('active');
  }
}
```

If you will create a working snippet (or fiddle or something) I could show you how to fix it.

Comment: My pleasure   Good luck 

Comment: you should use onClose instead of onSelect

Answer (score 0):

You need to set class on a select event of jquery datepicker. this need to help you.

```
// input
 function setclass()
{
  tmpval = $(this).val();
  if(tmpval == '')
  {
    $(this).removeClass('active')
    .siblings('label').removeClass('active');
  }
  else 
  {
    $(this).addClass('active')
    .siblings('label').addClass('active');
  }
}
$('input[type="text"], input[type="password"]').on('keyup blur', function()
{
  setclass();
});

$('.datepicker').datepicker({
changeMonth: true,
changeYear: true,
yearRange: "-100:+0",
onSelect: function(dateText) 
  {
  setclass()
  }
});
```